# Отображение данных с другого сайта в реальном времени

Tags: веб-программирование, frontend

Есть два сайта, на одном из них содержатся данные, на другом сайте необходимо эти данные выводить в реальном времени, т.е. при изменении информации на первом сайте, на втором также должна информация обновится сразу же. С владельцами первого сайта все обговорено. Проблема в том, что никак не могу найти хотя бы намек, где искать по поводу изменений в **РЕАЛЬНОМ** времени. AJAX, как я понял, поддерживает именно изменение на сервере. Есть идеи, каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: Вам необходима технология WebSocet, устанавливает постоянное соединение с сервером и отображает данные в реальном времени

Comment: а выводить данные надо в совершенно другом виде?

Comment: Данные на первом сайте представлены таблицей, моя задача сейчас их именно достать, пока вид не важен
А реально ли это сделать без изменений в коде у первого сайта, с которого берут данные, или это уже бред?

Answer (score 1):

Если с владельцем чужого сайта(siteB) есть договоренность, то можно делать так:

1. в .htaccess на siteB добавить:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

2. Там-же сделать скрипт, который будет выдавать самую последнюю информацию из БД
3. На вашем сайте в нужной странице вставить JS-код:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     // раз в 10 секунд запрашиваем данные
     get_remote_data_interval = setInterval(get_remote_data, 10000);
   });

   function get_remote_data(){
     $.get("http://siteB/export_data.php?param=value", function(data){
       if (data.length > 0 ) {
         for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
           $('#remote_data_list').append("<li>"+data[i].text+"</li>");
         }
       }
     });
   }
   ```